# Functions that need information from each other in python

Tags: python, function

Having trouble with figuring out how 2 functions can call on each other. I need num_sides from report() in polygon_area and I need polygon_area added to the for loop in report. It tells me that the local variable is referenced before the assignment. Also if remove the poly parameter from report() I get a rep = report(side_length)
TypeError: report() missing 1 required positional argument: 'poly'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import math

def main():
    side_length = get_side_length()
    rep = report(side_length, poly)
    poly = polygon_area(rep, side_length)

def get_side_length():
    side_length = int(input('Input a side length: '))
    return side_length

def report(side_length, poly):
    print('side length \t number of sides \t area')
    for num_sides in range(3, 10):
        print(side_length,'\t\t', num_sides, '\t\t', poly)
    return num_sides
    
def polygon_area(rep, side_length):
    area = (num_sides * side_length * side_length) \
            / (4 * math.tan(math.pi / num_sides))
    return area

main()
```

Comment: You're code is riddled with errors. There are variables that you are calling for but you havnt even declared. like `side` inside of `report` function. In `main` you call `poly` to `report` but poly is declared after that call and it's not even used inside `report`. Remember that python reads from top to bottom. If you call for something that isnt declared until after the call. Then its undefined and will throw an exception.

Comment: I think you need to rethink the structure of this program. Try and split it up into different steps: get inputs; calculate data; show data

Comment: Bad code, `poly` not declared and you invoke it, change the logic and in any case use global variables

Comment: What do you mean by "I need num_sides from report"? `num_sides` is just a temporary variable during iteration.

Comment: It makes no sense to return it, it's just the last value of the iteration.

Comment: You need to explain what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You wrote four functions without doing any testing.  As a result, your program contains multiple problems.  A Stack Overflow question has to address a *single* issue.  Return to your tutorial materials, learn how to use functions, their parameters, and their local variables.  When you have *one* remaining sticking point, *then* you have a question to ask.  The posted code is simply too broad.

Comment: Are you trying to print the area of polygons with different number of sides and the same side length? You should put the loop in `main()`.

Comment: Sorry side was supposed to be side_length. I've been playing with this code half of the day so I've made a lot of changes. Poly is used inside of report in the print statement and it is declared after report but if I were to swap calling poly and rep in main then I would get the same error, just flip-flopped because report() needs info from polygon_area() and polygon_area() needs info from report.

Comment: It's a homework assignment and it wants the for loop in report()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop should not be in `report()`. You should loop in `main()`, calling `polygon_area` for each number of sides, and then call `report()` to print that line of the report.

```
import math

def main():
    side_length = get_side_length()
    print('side length \t number of sides \t area')
    for num_sides in range(3, 10):
        area = polygon_area(num_sides, side_length):
        report(num_sides, side_length, area)

def get_side_length():
    side_length = int(input('Input a side length: '))
    return side_length

def report(num_sides, side_length, poly):
    print(side_length,'\t\t', num_sides, '\t\t', poly)
    
def polygon_area(num_sides, side_length):
    area = (num_sides * side_length * side_length) \
            / (4 * math.tan(math.pi / num_sides))
    return area

main()
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Barmar, I was calling polygon_area in main. Calling it in the for loop in report() brought it all together. We just started functions in class a week ago so I didn't know that we could do that. Thank you!